# strtok() segmentation fault on empty string input

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_LENGTH 1024

char *readline(FILE* fp, int max_length)
{
    //The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional
    char *str;
    int ch;
    int len = 0;
    int current_max = max_length;

    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*current_max);
    if(!str)
        return str;

    while((ch = fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        /* Separate newline handling from EOF handling */
        if((char)ch == '\n')
        {
            str[len] = '\0';
            return str;
        }
        str[len++] = ch;

        if(len == current_max)
        {
            current_max = current_max + max_length;
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*current_max);
            if(!str)
                return str;
        }
    }
    str[len] = '\0';

    return str;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *input, *token;

    input = readline(stdin, MAX_INPUT_LENGTH);

    printf("BEFORE\n");
    token = strtok(input, " "); //Segmentation Fault Here
    printf("AFTER"); //control never reaches here on " " or "\n" input.
}
```

In the above snippet, I am trying to tokenize strings on whitspace as delimiter. Whenever I give input as a `newline(press ENTER)` or `a sequence of whitespaces`, the `strtok()` call segfaults. From what I understand, it should return `NULL` which I should be handling in sanity check later, but that is not really happening.

Please help me, what am I missing here ?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: How do you know your `malloc()` is success?

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @SouravGhosh it's a success because, I do check for that in the original code and for non-empty string input like "hello world", the program works fine as expected.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/YoSTm6

Comment: Or are you trying to *use* the value of `token` without checking whether it is NULL?

Comment: @SouravGhosh MCVE created. I checked on Ideone, it's not reproducing the same error, but don't know why on my machine it's giving a segmentation fault.

Comment: @rici please check the update to question, thanks

Comment: What is the actual error message? Your updated question is not causing any fault here, but `token == NULL`. Are you *sure* this is your code, that you are not using `token`?

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis of where the fault is occurring is incorrect

```
printf("AFTER"); //control never reaches here on " " or "\n" input.
```

Actually, control does reach there. You just don't see the "AFTER" message because there's no newline or flush there. Change the code to this and the mystery will go away:

```
printf("AFTER\n");
```

I'll bet you couldn't replicate the fault with your MCVE because it does reach the end of `main`, which flushes output. You forgot the "V" in MCVE. You need to verify that it replicates the problem.